# How to add firebase push notifications to Ionic v1 project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-v1, ionic-cli, ionic-zip, ionic.io

Im kinda new to Ionic and I have a basic ionic creator v1 project with me. I have downloaded the zip file export and I already have Ionic CLI @ latest version. I saw many tutorials on how to add firebase push notifications but they are all for Ionic v3 projects. So how should I add push notifications to my Ionic v1 project?

Comment: You can use [**this plugin**](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

Comment: @obsidian Age I dont know how to install this on ionic. I found a tutorial for this but that was for Ionic3. Where can I find a tutorial?